# Complete multi language website in php

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, internationalization

I need an idea on how to make a complete multilanguage website. I came across many ways some are having an xml file to have template bits translated. This works if I only want the main template. But even the content will be translated.

For example I have a new entry in english, it should be translated to 4 other languages. Most attributes are common.

What i reached so far is by creating a table for the main website template with attributes:
lang, tag, value
In my template it will do a match on lang and tag.

What is the best way to translate the rest of the website (dynamic php pages using mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table for languages as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `language` (
 `langid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `language` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`langid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Then for example you have a table for posts as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
 `postid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `langid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `content` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`postid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In the post table you need a key like `langid`, which refers to the specific language in the language table. In you dashboard you will have something as below:
[image]
Each textbox refers to that specific language.
You should have another table for site's menus, and put langid foreign key in there. You should be well on your way.

Comment: and where do i store different languages for each post? i think this is my main question. i already have table post created. but i created post_lan table with all languages. but now i have different id for each language and i was seeking best practice for this.

Comment: @fawzib, in the post table itself you'll have a langid which referes to the language. In the answer you can see that I have added langid. It refers to the language.

Comment: how i can keep the same post id the same in all languages. it used to be based on auto increment. later i will do a query on postid + langid. this will allow me to switch between languages based on id.

Comment: @fawzib, fair enough you need a junction table. In the junction table you need to store `title`,`content`,`pid`,`langid`. In the post table you will keep all the data that you needed as `date`,`pid`,`views`,`comment_no`,etc. Now if you want to fetch a specific post in a specific language you need to join tables `post` and `junction_post_lang`.

Comment: This looks pretty good, I just have one question. In case you create a new post/content how is it going to be the INSERT since the content and the language is going to be in different tables? In this case wouldn't be more logic to have 1 table with eng_content and fre_content???

Comment: @Lykos, what if you want to add another language after 5 years? you need to alter the table for every new laguage which is not efficient.

Comment: @phpGeek: So The tables required will be 3(posts-languages-junction_table) or just 2(posts-junction_table) ?? In my case I only need 2 languages.

Answer (score 2):

Look into gettext extension - http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Then use a program like [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) or [simplepo](http://code.google.com/p/simplepo/) to do the actual editing of the language files

IMO, this is the best way I have found for a multilingual site

You can also look into the [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) module

Comment: thanks for the links, but they should be based on the database and i was seeking a way to organize my table structure for this purpose.